# Connecting to my local network through OpenVPN (using PiVPN): inconsistently works

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, raspberry-pi

I have setup PiVPN on my home network and use TunnelBlick on my MacBook to connect when not at home. I have noticed that from some networks, when connected to my VPN, I can access devices on my local home network (192.168.1.1 for example to access my router admin page as well as other devices). However, on some networks, this does not work and if I go to something like 192.168.1.1 it will send me to what I assume is the router admin page for the network i'm currently connected to (and I cannot connect to any devices on my home network).

As I'm not well versed in how OpenVPN works, I'm not sure how to approach researching how/why I get this behavior. Why does this sometimes work, but sometimes not? What technique(s) are used to allow me to access my home network in the first place? Why might this technique not work in some cases? What questions should I be asking? I'm happy to read up more on this, if someone could be kind enough to point me in the right direction.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart thank for you taking time to answer.  It looks like this was the issue, my home network using the (very typical) 192.168.1.xxx address range and this was conflicting with some networks I would connect to.  After posting this I found an older post that gives more detailed info if anyone stumbles on this and wants [a more detailed answer](https://superuser.com/questions/604267/vpn-on-same-ip-range)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your internal IP addresses to ones that are not commonly used by consumer routers.

The reason it's inconsistent is because there will be a conflict in the scheme you are trying to use vs the local router outside of your home network that you are connected to. The router will not know the difference between the subnet that it controls and the private address space of your VPN.

You could use any of the private addressing spaces that are not commonly used by default. Try using 10.10.100.0 255.255.255.0 & 10.10.200.0 255.255.255.0 and see if it is consistent.

Similar thread as a reference:
[VPN on same IP Range](https://superuser.com/questions/604267/vpn-on-same-ip-range)